# Is it possible to have a javascript function in php

Tags: php, javascript

I have a program which records the time when user clicks the button I have written the timer script in javascript now i want to include this function inside php how can do this.

Thank you,

Swarna

Comment: output it like you do with html or anything else...? php executes php (server side usually), js is executed by the client (the one "reading" also the html or whatever the server is sending).

Comment: As said by you, you can't. You could however call a php script with ajax to store that time.

Comment: @simon i want to use the result to store it in the database

Comment: @thisMayhem i don't have any idea about ajax can you tell me how to do that

Comment: @Shin basically my program is a image slideshow each image pausing for 3  seconds an in that span user has to take a decision by clicking the button..alert message is displayed along with the message i need to store the time taken by user to click the button.

Comment: @Shruti I see space for ajax as an answer already say. No other way, otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ajax to send the click time details to a php script that will `do something` with it. ie: log to a database the time of the click.

Comment: Take a look at the jQuery framework it makes ajax calls simple http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I could never explain all of ajax here but follow the advice givin about going the jquery way. Its easy and there are a ton of good examples.